# Why does current glade modify the UI generated by a old glade?

Tags: gtk3, glade

I'm trying to modify sligthly the https://gitlab.com/robru/gottengeography/-/blob/master/data/gottengeography.ui file, which was created with (supposedly) `glade` in 2012, but when I open and save it (without modifications) in my ubuntu 20.04 system (my glade is 3.22.2-1), the UI I get in the python-gtk3 app is quite different from the original one.

I need a way to apply some very little modifications, but `glade` saves it as a (supposedly) quite different file.

Could the new `glade` have some incompatibility with the file generated by the 2012 one?

What should I do in order not to loose the UI which is interpreted now?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in Glade (and is the reason why some GNOME developers [hold the opinion you should not use it](https://blogs.gnome.org/christopherdavis/2020/11/19/glade-not-recommended/)).

Unfortunately, there is at the moment very little to do about it. There are some [projects](https://gitlab.gnome.org/jpu/cambalache) that are in the making to manage UI files for GTK4, but I don't know of any effort to backport it to GTK3.

I'm afraid at this point the best you can do, is to just manually edit the XML files in your IDE to do what you want.